# Office Online server connection with SharePoint 2016 for internal and external URLs?

Tags: 2016, oos

I have configured SharePoint 2016 with two URLs:

Internal URL: `http://connect.pm.world.net` and

(External) Internet URL: `https://connect.worldna.com`

Now for Office Online server below will be the OOS configuration command:

```
New-OfficeWebAppsFarm -InternalUrl "https://oos.pm.world.net" -ExternalUrl "https://oos.worldna.com" -CertificateName "OfficeWebApps Certificate" -EditingEnabled
```

And the certificate "OfficeWebApps Certificate" is SAN which contains urls: `https://oos.pm.world.net` and `https://oos.worldna.com`

And as per my organization domain settings, internal url FQDN can be only `pm.world.net` and external urls FQDN can be only `worldna.com`.

Now on SharePoint server I will run below command:

```
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName 'oos.pm.world.net'
```

So my query is that the above settings and command will work? And my internal and external users can access office online features?